# Why all class files are creating with .vb extension and not as .cs file in my Visual Studio? I need .cs file

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2012, c#

When I tried to create a class file in Windows Form in my Visual Studio it's creating `.vb` file and not `.cs` one. Not only in Windows Form but also in my MVC projects. Why it's creating `.vb` file? How do I change that `.vb` to `.cs` in all my projects. Did I select a wrong category while installing visual studio? If this question is not suitable to `Stackoverflow.com` can any one please migrate this question to appropriate Stack Exchange site.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Because you started Visual Basic project.  
In order to get files with .cs extension you have to create C# project solution.

Comment: Surely it is because you got started with a Visual Basic project.  Pick a C# project next time.

Comment: Do I need to uninstall Visual Studio and reinstall it using C#?

Comment: It's a question for me and I don't understand why people are down voting this?

Comment: I'm not kidding. I'm new to Visual Studio so asking like this. Please guide me

Comment: Visual Studio is used to build different kind of applications in different languages. All these info should be given before starting the project. I suggest to read some introductory tutorial on Visual Studio otherwise you will have difficult times ahead. [See a quick start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492171.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Steve for guiding me. Definitely I will go through this link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you started Visual Basic project.
In order to get files with .cs extension you have to create C# project solution.
You don't have to uninstall Visual Studio since it comes with "pre-installed" languages like VB.net, C#.net etc...

[image]

Comment: Can someone give a comment before down voting?  
Since, this is an answer to his question.

Comment: Thanks a lot Hoh. Now only understood. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome @Sathiya. If my answer helped you, please up vote it and select it as an final answer.

Comment: Yup! Me too wondering why people down voted your answer. It's really useful for a beginner like me.

Comment: I up-voted your answer and tried to accept the answer and it's asking me to wait for 3 minutes. Will accept your answer after 3 minutes. Thanks alot for your answer.